# Mounting ACL on a UNIX/Apache Server

Tags: apache-2.2, unix, access-control-list

Does the following command turn on ACL for the entire set of directories on my server?

```
mount -o remount,rw,acl /
```

I believe that it does due to the ending forward slash. If that's the case, should I only be mounting ACL on the directories and sub-directories that I want to share access too? So would that command look like this?

```
mount -o remount,rw,acl /sub-dir/that_I_want_to_share/
```

And where do I run this command? At the command prompt in my telnet session? In a config file of some sort (if so, what/where)?

And if I turn on ACL do I need to turn it on again every time I restart Apache or reboot the server?

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount options apply to filesystems, not directories.  If you only have one filesystem mounted, then  `mount -o remount,rw,acl /` will probably do what you want.  However, if you have other filesystems mounted, you would need to perform the same operation for each filesystem.

Typically, you would never enter this command manually outside of a test situation.  Normally, you specify filesystem options in your `/etc/fstab`.  For example, if your `fstab` file looks like this:

```
/dev/vg0/root           /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
```

You would change it to look like this:

```
/dev/vg0/root           /                       ext3    defaults,acl        1 1
```

Next time you boot server, the `acl` option would be enabled for this filesystem.

Comment: Got it, thanks @larsks. I looked at my fstab and it only has "defaults,usrquota,bind,noauto". I'll look to have it turned on by my sysadmin.